# mysql locks relation to indexes

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to understand the relation between locks and indexes.

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col1 VARCHAR(255),
    col2 INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO example_table (col1, col2) VALUES ('a',1); 
INSERT INTO example_table (col1, col2) VALUES ('b',2); 
INSERT INTO example_table (col1, col2) VALUES ('c',3); 
INSERT INTO example_table (col1, col2) VALUES ('d',4);
```

when im running the following queries on 2 separate transactions im getting

```
SELECT * FROM example_table where col1="a" FOR UPDATE;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM example_table where col1="b" FOR UPDATE;
```

and when running the 2nd query, it waits for the 1st to release the exclusive lock.

but if I add an index to col1, running these 2 slecet queries do not wait for each other's lock.

my question is: why when querying `select ... for update` on non **indexed** query the who table is locked and when querying `select ... for update` on **indexed** column only the required rows are locked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` locks every row that it examines, not just the ones that are selected.

When there's no index on `col1`, it has to examine every row to see if the condition is true, so the whole table is locked.

When there's an index on `col1`, it can use that index to find the rows that match the condition, and only those rows will be locked.

Comment: thanks for your answer . what about where statement like: WHERE a='a' and b='b'. when only a is indexed and b is not? i see it behaves like the case where column is indexed

Comment: It will lock all rows where `a='b'`, including the ones where `b != 'b'`.

Comment: @yuria - In that case, it would be better to have `INDEX(col1, col2)`.  If you have further questions or concerns, please provide the "real" query; this simplification of your question is about to lead to wrong conclusions.